# concatenate filenames

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code in child window which is working but what I want to do is instead of using response.write I want to use label control or  to display all the filename like this:

music.pdf, inventory.doc

My Ultimate goal is to pass the values in string (e.g.: "music.pdf, inventory.pdf" ) to the parent window.

How do I do it?

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Try
        '' Get the HttpFileCollection
        Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
        For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
            Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)
            If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/ServerName/DirectoryName") & "\"" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
                Response.Write("<b>File: </b>" & hpf.FileName & " <b>Size:</b> " & hpf.ContentLength & " <b>Type:</b> " & hpf.ContentType & " Uploaded Successfully! <br/>")
            Else
                Response.Write("Please select a file to upload.")
            End If
        Next i

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: They really need to fix the VB comment issue.

Comment: I would also recommend using the Path.Combine method instead of the string concat for resolving the path to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way I would do it but you asked for your code to work with a Label.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Label id="lblUploadMsg" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

**Code:**

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Try
        '' Get the HttpFileCollection
        Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files

        lblUploadMsg.Text = String.empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
            Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)
            If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/ServerName/DirectoryName") & "\"" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
                lblUploadMsg.Visible = True;                   
                lblUploadMsg.Text +="<b>File: </b>" & hpf.FileName & " <b>Size:</b> " & hpf.ContentLength & " <b>Type:</b> " & hpf.ContentType & " Uploaded Successfully! <br/>"


            Else
                lblUploadMsg.Text="Please select a file to upload."
            End If
        Next i

        ''HTML Encode lblUploadingMsg.Text after

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't the lblUploadMsg.Text = String.empty keep clearing out the label?

Comment: Bug, I moved it up where it should have been.

Comment: I was on the right track but didn't utilize the "+=" operator.  How dumb of me.  Thanks for the solution!!!

Comment: As below, it seems that the Label.Text property sends unescaped HTML to the browser. Does `hpf.FileName` have a chance of containing HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `<asp:BulletedList>`, which is an ASP.NET server control for an unordered list `<ul>`.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:BulletedList 
   id="uploadedFiles" runat="server"></asp:BulletedList>
```

Instead of `Response.Write()` each file, simply:

```
  Dim displayText as String = string.Format("File: {0}  Size: {1}  Type: {2} Uploaded Successfully", _
          hpf.FileName ,hpf.ContentLength ,hpf.ContentType)

  uploadedFiles.Items.Add(New ListItem(displayText, hpf.FileName ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a label control onto the form/control and then instead of using Response.Write, why not use a string builder and append all of the output to that in the loop. Once you have processed all of the files set the Label control's Text property of the string builder ToString method.

Hope this helps

Comment: pretty much as per @PhilPursglove 's answer; if further is required then let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx) overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string builder to join strings.  Strings in .NET are immutable, so Join and any other operators are memory intensive

Comment (not on the question, but I noticed it in your code) Use Path.Combine and any other Path functions.  Amazingly easy to forget that they exist and have saved me millions of headaches.

Comment: This will not accomplish the output that the OP wants.

Comment: Does String.Join not use efficient methods before returning a string? I.e., I thought that String.Join uses a string builder during joining, and then returns an immutable string?

Comment: @Nate Noonen: My earlier comment was to an earlier version of this answer.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/StringBuilder_vs_String.aspx

I stand corrected: "The shiny performance saving StringBuilder does not help in all cases and is, in some cases, slower than other functions. When you want to have good string concatenation performance I recommend strongly that you use String.Join which does an incredible job."  I assumed builder was "always" the best option.  You learn something new every day.  I love this field :D

Comment: And the best quote from the article:  "After taking a deep look with Reflector I found that String.Join has the most efficient algorithm implemented which allocates in the first pass the final buffer size and then memcopy each string into the just allocated buffer. This is simply unbeatable."

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Response.Write` outside of the loop over `i`.

Inside of `i` loop, keep track using a `List<String>`. Then, after the loop, use the `Response.Write`, to write a `String.Join` over the `List.ToArray` with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Label control won't honour your `<b>` tags - what you're looking for here is to use the Literal control. Try something like this:

In your markup:

```
<asp:literal runat="server" id="UploadedFileInfoLiteral" />
```

In your code-behind:

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
Try
    '' Get the HttpFileCollection
    Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
    Dim FileInfoStringBuilder As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile

    For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
        hpf = hfc(i)
        If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
            hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/ServerName/DirectoryName") & "\"" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
            FileInfoStringBuilder.Append("<strong>File: </strong>" & hpf.FileName & " <strong>Size:</strong> " & hpf.ContentLength & " <strong>Type:</strong> " & hpf.ContentType & " Uploaded Successfully! <br/>")
        Else
            FileInfoStringBuilder.Append("Please select a file to upload.")
        End If
    Next

    UploadedFileInfoLiteral.Text = FileInfoStringBuilder.ToString()

Catch ex As Exception

End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Can an HTTP POST filename as reported by a client include invalid Filename characters, such as `"<script>"`?

Comment: @maxwellb I don't know, but it'd make for an interesting attack, wouldn't it ;-)

Comment: @maxwellb Angle-brackets and double-quotes are invalid in a filename, however it appears you could *potentially* construct a filename like this using &codes for the angle-brackets...

Comment: Yes, I mean, if I sent a POST header with a custom client, which included `"<script>"` in the filename value of my `multipart/form-data`, the file contents would be intact, and probably valid. So, in _this_ case, OP would fail on the `Server.MapPath`, but if the server stores to a BLOB, or an autogenerated server path, and reports the unsanitized "filename" back to the client, there could be a potential attack.

Comment: Correction. It would fail on `hpf.SaveAs( ... & hpf.FileName )`.